# Sample a Range by another Range

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I want to "sample" a `Range` using another `Range`. For example:

```
def sample(in: Range, by: Range): Range = ???

// note: Range equals broken!
assert(sample(3 to 10     , 1 to 2     ).toVector == (4 to 5     ).toVector)
assert(sample(3 to 10     , 1 to 4 by 2).toVector == (4 to 6 by 2).toVector)
assert(sample(3 to 10 by 2, 1 to 2     ).toVector == (5 to 7 by 2).toVector)
assert(sample(3 to 10 by 2, 1 to 4 by 2).toVector == (5 to 9 by 4).toVector)
```

How to define the `sample` method?

Comment: My attempt was getting too messy in an attempt to actually be correct for all cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an attempt. I haven't tested all possible combinations. For simplicity, the `by` argument must have a start greater than or equal to zero, and a positive step.

```
def sample(in: Range, by: Range): Range = {
  val drop  = by.start
  val stepM = by.step
  require(drop >= 0 && stepM > 0)
  val in1 = in.drop(drop)
  val in2 = if (stepM == 1) 
    in1 
  else if (in1.isInclusive)  // copy-method is protected :(
    new Range.Inclusive(start = in1.start, end = in1.end, step = in1.step*stepM)
  else
    new Range          (start = in1.start, end = in1.end, step = in1.step*stepM)
  in2.take(by.size)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By changing the `sample` return type to `IndexedSeq[Int]`, got this simple solution,

```
def sample(in: Range, by: Range): IndexedSeq[Int] = {
  in intersect (in.start+by.start to in.start+by.end by by.step)
}
```

which quests for the intersection between `in` and `by` shifted with `in.start`.

For the assertions refactored accordingly, these two pass,

```
assert(sample(3 to 10     , 1 to 2     ) == (4 to 5     ))
assert(sample(3 to 10     , 1 to 4 by 2) == (4 to 6 by 2))
```

and these two fail,

```
assert(sample(3 to 10 by 2, 1 to 2     ) == (5 to 7 by 2)) // intersect at 5 only
assert(sample(3 to 10 by 2, 1 to 4 by 2) == (5 to 9 by 4)) // empty intersect
```